# "CGImageBlock's rowbytes doesn't match the CGImage rowbytes!" warning message

Tags: objective-c, core-graphics

I am creating a CIImage object for CIFilter to add filters.
When I am creating the CIImage object, I see a warning message "CGImageBlock's rowbytes doesn't match the CGImage rowbytes!".
This warning message only appears when I test the App on a real device.
When I use simulator, such warning message does not appear.

I normally create the CIImage object from a UIImage object using one of the following 2 ways:

**Method 1:**

```
NSString * path = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/an_image_file_name.png"];
UIImage * uiimage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];
CIImage * ciimage = [[CIImage alloc] initWithImage:uiimage]; // This shows warning (on real device testing)
```

**Method 2:**

```
UIImage * uiimage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"filename_in_bundle.png"];
CIImage * ciimage = [[CIImage alloc] initWithImage:uiimage]; // This does not show warning
```

The problem is:
Only method 1 shows the warning message.
I tried to find such issue from the internet but I could not find anything useful.
Although the app runs well on the device, I am not sure if this will cause any issue in the final product.

Note: I am using Xcode 4.3.2 with iOS 5 SDK

[image]